# Woocommerce if product has upsells show badge in product listing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-theming

I'm trying to make a dynamic product badge show in the product listings on a Woocommerce site. The product badge should only show if the product has upsells assigned to it.

I just did this on the single product page with good results using this code in the `content-single-product.php` file:

```php
<?php if ( isset( $product ) && is_product() ) {
    $upsells = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $product->get_upsells() : $product->get_upsell_ids();
    if ( count( $upsells ) > 0 ) { ?>
        <span class="more_variants">Finns i fler varianter</span>
<?php } } ?>
```

However, since the product data for upsells isn't collected for single products in the listings I tried another approach by implementing this code to `functions.php`:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'related_upsell_products', 15 );

function related_upsell_products() {
    global $product;

    if ( isset( $product ) && is_product() ) {
        $upsells = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $product->get_upsells() : $product->get_upsell_ids();

        if ( count( $upsells ) > 0 ) {
            echo '<span class="more_variants">Finns i fler varianter</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

The code in `functions.php` doesn't give me an error nor does it give me the result I want neither. It returns nothing. My honest thought was that `global $product;` would give me the extra product data needed to get information if the product in particular has upsell products assigned to it or not.

Any thoughts is very welcome! I've searched the forums and do not get much results about working with upsells in this way with Woocommerce at all. Probably because it's not very common to work with upsells as variants instead of variable products..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're on the `shop` page, when you say *"products in the listings"*. If so, then you would need to:

- Change your conditional check to `is_shop()`.
- Also call your `global $product` after you've checked for the shop page.

So your entire code would be something like this:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'related_upsell_products', 15);

function related_upsell_products()
{
    if (is_shop()) {
        global $product;

        $upsells = version_compare(WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<') ? $product->get_upsells() : $product->get_upsell_ids();

        if (count($upsells) > 0) {
            echo '<span class="more_variants">Finns i fler varianter</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: I guess sometimes the answer is right in front of you. Thanks a lot for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: LOL! That's absolutely true. You're welcome!